# Resizing DIV table for all mobile devices

Tags: php, html, css, media-queries, responsive

I am having trouble getting a table I have to resize properly on mobile devices. (iPhone, Pixel, etc.) It is due to the fact that my DIV table is too wide for mobile. It looks just fine on iPad, Laptop etc but for phones it is too wide. I've used media queries for my navbar but this is a little more complex as it is a table I am displaying from PHP.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>


        .table{ 
                display: table;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                text-align: left;

            }

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

}

            .tr{ 
                display: table-row; 
                padding: 1px;
            }
            .td{ 
                display: table-cell;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .padding {
                padding: 12px;
                margin: auto;
            }


        </style>
    </head>
<body> 

<div>
    <div class ="top">
            <center><h1 class="profile">Ticket #<?php echo $id ?></h1></center>
    </div>

    <hr>

        <?php     
            $sql = "select a.id, a.lname, a.fname, a.phonenum, a.room, a.building, a.issue, a.start_time, a.end_time, a.description, a.username
            from appointments as a
            where a.email = '". $_SESSION['email'] ."' and id = '$id'
            ";


            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo " <div class='table'>
                <div class='tr'>
                <div class='td'><b>Ticket #</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Username</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Name</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Residence</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Issue</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Date</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Appointment Time</b></div>
                </div>";
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $starttime = strtotime($row["start_time"]); //converts date time received from MySQL into a string
                    $endtime = strtotime($row["end_time"]);
                    $date = date("m/d/y", $starttime);
                    $start = date("g:i A", $starttime);
                    $end = date("g:i A", $endtime);
                    $building = str_replace('_',' ', $row["building"]);
                    echo "<div class='tr'>
                    <div class='td'>".$row["id"]."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$row["username"]."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$row["fname"].' '.$row["lname"]."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$building." ".$row["room"]."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$row["issue"]."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$date."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$start.'-'.$end."</div>
                    </div>";
                    $description = $row["description"];
                }
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<br><hr><p>
                <center><h2>Issue Description</h2></center>
                <center>$description</center <br><br>
                ";
            } else {
                echo "<br/>Error</b>";
            }

        ?>
</div>



<?php

require 'includes/footer.php';
```

Comment: Can I see a link to the working/running code?

Comment: Not enough, no. Can you include the generated source? Any modern browser should let you view that and this will be of much greater help than the server-side code.

Comment: read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) it will help

Comment: [source](https://codepen.io/miller765/pen/jRPPqy) @AndyHoffman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. Under `600px` (I'm calling that mobile for this example), change the `table` display to `flex` (row direction) and each `tr` child display to `flex` as well (column direction).

The main bit I added is this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body .table {
    display: flex;  
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .table .tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .table .td {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

### Demo

```css
h2 {
  margin: 20px 45px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 20px 45px;
}

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(119, 13, 41);
}

ul.nav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
}

ul.nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgb(237, 235, 235);
  color: rgb(119, 13, 41);
}

ul.nav li a.active {
  background-color: rgb(169, 5, 51);
}

ul.nav li.right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul.nav li.right,
  ul.nav li {
    float: none;
  }
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  padding: 7px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}

th {
  padding: 7px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
}

</style></head><style>.table {
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .td {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 1px;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}

.padding {
  padding: 12px;
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body .table {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .table .tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .table .td {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="top">
    <center>
      <h1 class="profile">Ticket #123461</h1>
    </center>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td"><b>Ticket #</b></div>
      <div class="td"><b>Username</b></div>
      <div class="td"><b>Name</b></div>
      <div class="td"><b>Residence</b></div>
      <div class="td"><b>Issue</b></div>
      <div class="td"><b>Date</b></div>
      <div class="td"><b>Appointment Time</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">123461</div>
      <div class="td">username</div>
      <div class="td">John Doe</div>
      <div class="td">dorm 5</div>
      <div class="td">WiFi not working</div>
      <div class="td">06/01/19</div>
      <div class="td">12:00 PM-12:50 PM</div>
    </div>
  </div><br>
  <hr>
  <p>
  </p>
  <center>
    <h2>Issue Description</h2>
  </center>
  <center>In fermentum facilisis lorem in pharetra. Fusce massa arcu, tincidunt at arcu sed, pellentesque volutpat augue. Curabitur viverra mauris id magna ultricies tristique vitae nec sapien. Nam aliquet pulvinar tincidunt. Phasellus molestie in tellus vitae
    pharetra. Nunc facilisis mi tincidunt turpis elementum sodales. Vivamus sed molestie tellus, condimentum feugiat metus.</center><br>
</div>



<!-- Footer div -->
<div class="footer">
  <style>
    div.footer {
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/antibland/pen/YMXyZp)

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your swift reply! That actually looks great. That is just using CSS to resize and everything with the media queries correct? Just want to be sure I am understanding.

Comment: @TMiller96 Yes, I only added `CSS`. If you look at the [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/antibland/pen/YMXyZp), all I added was the `CSS` in the `CSS` column.

Comment: this did wonders. thank you so much! Green check certified. I will have to read more into css and these properties.  Thanks again!

Comment: @TMiller96 Thanks. Flexbox is magic! Here is the [definitive tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to read when you have some time.